# Apply a pattern to solid pixels and leave background transparent?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have an image:

- solid pixels
- transparent background

I wish to apply `-tile pattern:gray50` onto only the solid pixels, leaving the background transparent, so the result is:

- solid pixels with black/white pattern
- transparent background

The closest I have is:

```
magick \
\( -size 1216x342 pattern:gray50 \) \
input.png \
-compose Dst_In \
-composite \
output.png
```

which gets me:

- solid pixels with black/white pattern
- BUT a black background

I can't then do `-transparent black` because I need to keep the black pixels in the pattern.

What am I missing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

The pattern image needs to have `-alpha on` to activate the alpha channel.

```
magick \
\( -size 1216x342 pattern:gray50 -alpha on \) \
input.png \
-compose Dst_In \
-composite \
output.png
```